# How to convert Json data to panda datafame in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to convert web scraped json data to Panda Dataframe in Python.

```
      from requests import Request, Session
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, Timeout, TooManyRedirects
import json
import pandas as pd 

url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
parameters = {
  'start':'1',
  'limit':'5000',
  'convert':'USD'
}
headers = {
  'Accepts': 'application/json',
  'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': '8a7f806b-2635-4aed-96f0-5b350bbab953',
}

session = Session()
session.headers.update(headers)

try:
  response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
  data = json.loads(response.text)
  print(data)
except:
    print("error") 


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Comment: I think you need `pd.DataFrame(pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, 'data'))`